# String parsing based on escape character

Tags: c++, c, parsing

I am trying to parse the following string:

```
"USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_JETFLASH&PROD_TRANSCEND_8GB&REV_1100\00H8096XQ9UW1BQ5&0:JetFlash Transcend 8GB USB Device"
```

based on `'\'` (character)

Prob 1: but this character is considered as escape character

Prob 2: `\0` in the mid of the string is considered as the end of the string.

I tried so many ways.

(i) I tried to replace `'\'` with another character like `'$'` and tried to parse with `sscanf()` but it did not work.

Can you people suggest something?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[80] = "This is \www.tutorialspoint.com \website";
    const char s[2] = "\\";
    char *token;

    /* get the first token */
    token = strtok(str, s);

    /* walk through other tokens */
    while( token != NULL )
    {
      printf( " %s\n", token );

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Use [strtok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/strtok.html) instead of `sscanf`

Comment: The backslash is only an escape character in *literal* strings, i.e. strings you literally write in the source code. String you read from input (user, files, network) do *not* have backslash as an "escape" character.

Comment: And it's the *value* zero (character with ASCII code zero, a.k.a. the *literal* character `'\0'`) that is a string terminator. In a string, the character sequence `'\'` followed by `'0'` is not a string terminator.

Comment: you should post source code.

Comment: @Raja: I have posted source code please check it...

Comment: output the code before you parse it, and then tell us what you get for output. If your input string *really* contained \w (an [escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) which is not valid, i.e. which cannot be printed since it does not have any corresponding character, then your string wouldn't print like you show above, but I guesws instead would print like "This is ww.tutorialspoint.com ebsite"

Comment: @nyarlathotep: the output is This is www.tutorialspoint.com website

Comment: ok - decent compilers like g++ would warn you anyway that \w is not a valid escape sequence and will probably just remove the \

Comment: @nyarlathotep: you are right sir...But this string I am getting from user.My prog will take the string as an arguement and then parse it...this string is not const...it can be anyting...but I have to parse all string based on '\' only

Comment: as all the people tell you here: \ in string literals (i.e. in a string you hard-code into the program) is a bit different than \ in user input. in string literals, double the \

Comment: i believe this question has been answered. please accept my edit to your question to add the error msg, and accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make this modification
`char str[80] = "This is \\www.tutorialspoint.com \\website";`

With that, your output is:

```
This is 
www.tutorialspoint.com 
website
```

Remember: Any string literal that you use in code requires the escape sequence for backslash.

Comment: This is only for the string literal (i.e. the constant string you're using on the right hand side). You need to use \\ instead of \.

Comment: Raghav, problem is with the use of `\\` in string literals (you don't have this problem when you read the same string from an input or reading a file)

Comment: @Raja:But this string I am getting from user.My prog will take the string as an arguement and then parse it...this string is not const...it can be anyting...but I have to parse all string based on '\' only..

Comment: You're still confused about string literals and string assignment via user input. When you hard code a string in your program (called a literal), you need to use escape sequences. When you enter a string via std input, you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Remember **Escape Sequences (`\\`, `\n`, `\0`, etc.)are a single character.**

To have `\` character in a string which is initialized in the code itself, it is mandatory to use `\\` in the initialization string.

If you are providing input at runtime, then you should use `\` (Single BackSlash) for input, Providing input this way **will not** consider `\0` as ASCII-0 character, instead it will be treated as `\` followed by `0` (two characters).

In your case, you want to parse **"USBSTOR\D..."**, you can do it in either by storing it in a `const` string (Remember `\\` in this case) or by providing it as input form console or a disk file (Here you should use single `\`).

In any of the above ways, when you read the string, you will get the correct character expected, example, for first case `\\` will resolve to `\` when you read it or print it.

Comment: No it wont! Each of them are separate characters. '\0' is a single character. "blah\0blah" contains 10 characters.

Comment: @RaghavGuar : The end of string is ASCII-0 valued character, which is not printable hence it is denoted in C by `\0`. Now if you are reading a string char by char and you get a sequence of two chars '\' and '0' , that will not denote end of string, thats simply two characters.